# is there way to create array without key in cJSON

Tags: cjson

1.i need print json format like
{
"numport":1
[
{
"Port":1
"value":234
},{
"Port":2
"value":2344
}
]

Answer (score 0):

What you printed is not a valid json string. So cJSON won't be able to create it.
You can validate your string here:
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/